# How does the shell get the environment variables set by python

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables

Python uses "os.environ ['key'] = value" to set environment variables, can the value be obtained in the shell

Comment: "The" shell is an inaccurate view - there isn't just one. For the shell you launched Python from, this is not possible.

Comment: You can modify the environment of the python program itself and the changes will be visible to any process which you run from your python program. But you cannot modify the environment of the shell which was used to run the python program (not without some tricks).

Comment: This is one of the possibilities: `eval \`python -c 'print "key=value"'\``

Comment: Like this you can modify the environment variable of the shell which was used to run the python program. The trick is that your program just prints `key=value` and the shell interprets this as a command which should be performed. In other words, when you run this the shell already *knows* that you want to modify its environment. If you don't provide the shell this information and just run your program like 'python program.py', then you cannot modify the shell variables (unless you are a hacker, but then you would know the answer yourself).